# What's the difference between aio_read and read/EWOULDBLOCK?

Tags: c++, c, linux, asynchronous, io

In aio_read, we use aio_error function on a aiocb struct to check whether operation is finished. To me, it seems as polling and same as read followed by checking EWOULDBLOCK as a return value.

Comment: `aiocb` has also `aio_sigevent` field, that you can use for the callback so no need for polling by `aio_error`.

Comment: If you are calling `aio_error` right after `aio_read` then there is clearly no point in using asynchronous io. Actually you should provide some example code for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> we use aio_error function on a aiocb struct to check whether operation is finished.

No we don't. We use it to check whether it finished *with an error.*

> To me, it seems as polling and same as read followed by checking EWOULDBLOCK as a return value.

No. If the operation hasn't finished, with or without an error, it continues, asynchronously. EWOULDBLOCK means the operation *has* finished and without transferring any data.

You should certainly *not* 'poll' when using async I/O: you should just allow the completion handler to run and have *it* check what the result was.